# Finding the contraction of angles of a triangle as seen by an observer O

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, observers

> Three rods are joined to form a 45–45–90 triangle, which is placed at rest in the x′ y′ plane with its hypotenuse along the x′ axis. O′ moves away from O in the x direction at a speed of 0.92c. What are the angles of the triangle according to O?

I know that observer O, relative to whom O' is in motion, measures a shorter length but only along the direction of motion.

Suppose the proper length of the sides of the triangle (in the x'y' plane) is $L_0$ and since this triangle is right isosceles then the hypotenuse length is $L_0\sqrt{2}$.

The hypotenuse will contract since it's placed on the x'-axis so:
$$
L = L_0\sqrt{2} \, \times \,(1-v^2/c^2) = 0.554L_0
$$

Now for the sides, only the x component should contract so:
$$
L_x = L_0\cos45^{\circ} \times \, (1-v^2/c^2) = \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{25}L_0
$$
$$
L_y = L_0\sin45^{\circ} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
Therefore the side length with respect to O should be: $L = \sqrt{{L_x}^2 + {L_y}^2 } = 0.759L_0$

I think that observer O will not see a right triangle but I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: Questions of the type "How to calculate?" or "Check my calculations" tend to get closed. To try and get your question reopened, I suggest you remove the calculations and try to pin point what is confusing you or what you find contradictory. Also make it clear you are talking about relativity and length contraction and not just rely on the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your calculations are correct you could then use the property that similar triangles are rescaled versions of each other, meaning that the ratios of lengths should be equal.

Therefore if you manage to prove that $\frac{L_{hip}}{L_{left side}} \neq \frac{L_{hip}'}{L_{left side}'}$ ,where $L's$ are lengths from $O'$s frame of reference, then you will have proved that the triangle $\Delta '$ is not a rescalement of $\Delta$, so the internal angles have changed.


Now, to find the angles you can use the property that since the intial angles of the sides with respect to one frame of reference were equal, then these must also be equal in the new frame of reference. From there you can see that the height of the new triangle must be left unchanged (because the boost is perpendicular to the y direction) and compute the leftmost angle as $\theta_{left} = arcsin (\frac{Height'=Height}{L_{hip}/2})=arcsin (2\frac{Height'=Height}{L_{hip}})$ in the $O$ frame of reference. Since this must also be the angle of the rightmost side and the sum of the angles would still have to add up to $\pi$ then you can easily get the third angle from $\pi - 2\theta_{left}$.


Hope this helps!